# Java: Why would someone widen and shorten a variable?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I'm taking a java course on lynda.com, and the course was explaining how to "cast" a variable if you want to shorten it.

WIDENING: Widening a variable is making it larger (e.g. int int1 = 4030; long long1 = int1;)

SHORTENING: Shortening a variable is making it smaller, and requires special syntax. (e.g. int int2 = 5024; short int3 = (short) int2;).

So, my question is, why would anyone want to do this? What's the advantage? If you know you'll need to widen a variable at some point, why don't you just start it as that variable? And why would you want to make your data type smaller if you're shortening? If you think that it could be used like this:

```
byte byte1 = 127;

byte1++;

if (byte1 > 127) {
     short short1 = byte1;
}
```

(I know that this would give an error message, but you get the rough idea.)

You could do this, but why? It wouldn't save data, because it just adds more lines of code which would take up that data.

Comment: You might need to widen or shorten a variable if you were working with an interface requiring a different type than what your code happens to have.

Comment: Also, as a side note: You really don't need to think about how much memory you can save by writing less lines of code, that's pretty much never going to be of any significance (unless you are writing for a seriously restricted system). You should rather focus on how and which data structures you use for which problems so that you get the best (/very good) performance when working with a large amount of data.

Comment: One example of when shortening is needed is when you want to round a `double` to an `int`. An `int` is four bytes, while a `double` is eight. Thus, you must explicitly cast to an `int`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you know that you're working with an API that only works with `byte`s, why would you declare `int` variables and "shorten" it?

Comment: @Sweeper I was thinking more along the lines of you inherited some code whicb used `int` but then had a new need to interface with `byte`.

Comment: @Sweeper Because you might need to *do* something with the values the API provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons you might want to "shorten" a variable.

One is that an API or library you are working with requires data to be passed that is of a "shorter" type than the type you were using in your code.

Another is to save space. For example, if I only need to store a two digit number, using a `long` would be overkill as it would use much more system memory than is needed. This isn't something you normally need to worry too much about, but it could be an issue on certain systems or for very large projects.

There may be even more reasons; these are just a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you want to implement a `min(...)`  method to calculate the minimum of two numbers. You could simply write:

```
public static double min(double lhs, double rhs) {
    if (lhs >= rhs) {
        return (lhs);
    }
    // else if (rhs > lhs) {
    return (rhs);
    // }
```

and through auto-casting (or what you refer to as "widening"), you could call this method with all primitives in Java. The downside, however, is that the result would always be `double` and if you want to save it as an `int`, you would have to downcast the result:

```
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 100;
int max = (int) max(i1, i2);
```

It would be nice if the method returned an `int` iff. both parameters are `int`, a `long` iff. one parapeter is `long` and the other parameter is `long` or `int` and so on. This would result in the following code<sup>1</sup>:

```
public static int min(int lhs, int rhs) {
    if (lhs >= rhs) {
        return (lhs);
    }
    // else if (rhs > lhs) {
    return (rhs);
    // }
}

public static long min(long lhs, long rhs) {
    if (lhs >= rhs) {
        return (lhs);
    }
    // else if (rhs > lhs) {
    return (rhs);
    // }
}

public static float min(float lhs, float rhs) {
  if (lhs >= rhs) {
    return (lhs);
  }
  // else if (rhs > lhs) {
    return (rhs);
  // }

public static double min(double lhs, double rhs) {
    if (lhs >= rhs) {
        return (lhs);
    }
    // else if (rhs > lhs) {
    return (rhs);
    // }
}
```

Then you could write:

```
int i = 0;
long g = 1L;
float f = 2f;
double d = 3.0;

int intMax = max(i, i);
long longMax = max(i, g);
float floatMax = max(i, f);
double doubleMax = max(l, d);
```

Through the means of autocasting and [method overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), the most specific method will be called<sup>2,3</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> You culd write those methods for `byte`, `short` and `char`as well. I would not recommend doing so since all arithemtic operations in Java return at least something of type `int` (e.g. `byte + byte` will return an `int`). This is due to the fact that the JVM does not know of the primitives `boolean`, `char`, `byte` and `short`, they are represented as `int` (see [JLS §2.11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1)).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> The exact behaviour is specified in [JLS, §15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> This is actually the same mechanism used for[`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)'s implementation of `min(...)`, its implementation is slightly different.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can't avoid this if you must pass a value received from a function that is out of your control into another function that is also out of your control:

**package abc.def:**

```
public class Foo {
    public static long foo() { ... }
}
```

**package xyz.qwerty:**

```
public class Bar {
    public static void bar(int n) { ... }
}
```

**Your code:**

```
import xyz.qwerty.Bar;
import abc.def.Foo;

...

     Bar.bar((int)Foo.foo());
```

There may be intermediate variables temporarily holding the value received from `Foo.foo()` before it gets to `Bar.bar()` but that doesn't eliminate the inevitable need for converting from one type to another, which must happen somewhere in between.